# How to get correct date from Entity Framework in javascript

Tags: c#, datetime, angular, timezone

I don't see how to correctly convert date time from Entity Framework (in the back end) to Javascript (on the font end).

I my C# project, dates are created from Entity Framework queries against a SQL Server database, and are in local format, with `datetime.Kind = unspecified`.

I send my date with a websocket service, where date are serialized that way in the json structure: `2016/22/09T12:04:00`.

On the web side, where I used Angular2, dates are parsed with a time zone.

So my date `2016/22/09T12:04:00` is converted to `2016/22/09T12:04:00+02:00Z` = `2016/22/09T14:04:00`.

What is the best way to handle that problem? On the server side? On the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your `DateTime` values to `DateTimeOffset` (.Net type) and return it to the client it will handle them correctly.

If you can change your sql database it it is better to keep the dates in `datetimeoffset` (sql type) as it represent dates in the most precise format.

If you stick to you old types, at least you can consider keeping dates in UTC instead of the local time. You may get some surprises because of day-light time switching.

Comment: Perfect response, thank you! I migrated my database to use datetimeoffset in Sql Server. Having DateTimeOffset add the correct timezone to the serialized datetime in the web api response.